# Lotus Notes: Move email to a folder

Tags: lotus-notes

I have reading the shortcut keys for lotus notes, but could not find anything to move an email to a selected folder? Is there a shortcut key? if not, is there a way to creat such a shorcut
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct shortcut for move to folder. I always use the possibility to access the Action- Bar Buttons Pressing ALT + the number of the action- button that shows when holding the ALT- Key + the underlined character that shows, when the submenu opens.

Unfortunately the order and number of the buttons in the action bar differ from version to version. And you can only access the first 9 Actions with this method.

In Version 9 and the english template the right combination is: `ALT + 5 then M (Move to folder)`